# removing sensitive data from laptop (ssd drive) before sending to support

Tags: ssd, encryption, secure-erase

Here is my problem. My computer has a screen problem and needs to be sent to the manufacturer's support desk.

However I have some private files on the computer I dont want the support to (possibly) access. My computer is on win 8.1 pro and I have two internal ssd drives encrypted with bitlocker.

My question is, if I re-install windows (win 8.1 allows to do that easily), is anyone able to recover my files? I mean, the files were encrypted AND I re-installed the OS completely. Am I safe or I am missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sending it to the NSA for repair?  It sounds like overkill.  If they're encrypted, why would someone invest the time and energy to break the encryption?  You could remove the non-system drive.  If the system drive is a single partition and you wipe it to reinstall Windows, why would anyone suspect there was anything there to recover?  But yes, given enough time and the right tools, snippets of encrypted gibberish could be recovered.

Comment: Its almost a philosophical question bro. What does it mean to remove data from a computer? Type recover data on google and you ll find so many (probably fake) programs that pretend to recover lost data from even cruched hard disks that i wanted to be sure that i am safe. :-)

Comment: The real question is more who you want to protect it from.  Encryption will stop casual lookers.  Hard-deleted encryption won't be there unless someone thinks to search for remnants and scrapes the chips for whatever might be there, and then has the means to decrypt recovered remnants.  If you want to eliminate even that possibility, do random writing afterwards to the entire drive.  The techs are probably overworked and paid by the hour, though, so rather than spending time recovering your data, they are more likely to do a slipshod fix of the screen problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are so concerned about data privacy, I would like to recommend to do a complete disk wiping, that is by filling the disk with 0 or 1's, depending on the software used.
You should check this out.
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-hard-disk-cleaning-and-erasing-tools/

Comment: Thanks but as i said i have ssd and most of your links only work on hdds

Comment: Oops, my bad. 
I haven't tried this myself, but it's from cnet so it should be trustable.
http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-securely-erase-an-ssd-drive/

Answer (score 1):

What sort of screen problem? I'm sure you could use an external display to retrieve the files an back them up to a pen drive or external HDD. However, if you already re-installed windows, and formatted your HDD that the files were on, they are gone for sure and you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Forget the screen pb. My only worry is whether someone can access my data. It seems to me that things are not as simple as you suggest, unfortunately

Comment: When you installed Windows, did you format the main hard drive? If not, re-install Windows and on the partition page, press the Windows + R and run cmd. Then follow the instructions on [link](https://www.techhack.co.uk/2011/03/31/format-a-hard-drive-with-command-prompt/) to format the partition the files were stored on. After that, the files are erased and inaccessible.